# AppleScript: Overwrite A Text File

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that will save the number of times it has ever ran to a .txt file on my desktop. It is working great so far, except it won't overwrite the old data. Here is my code:

```
property numberOfUnitTests : 0

set numberOfUnitTests to numberOfUnitTests + 1
display dialog "Number of unit tests ran to date: " & numberOfUnitTests & ""


set the logFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "log.txt"
set the logText to "Number of unit tests ran to date: " & numberOfUnitTests & ""
try

    open for access file the logFile with write permission
    write ((logText) & return) to file the logFile starting at eof
    close access file the logFile
on error
    try
        close access file the logFile
    end try
end try
```

Now, this never over writes it. It just adds to the end of the file on a new line. I've tried adding in `set eof logFile to 0`, but then just nothing will save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending to the file:

```
starting at eof
```

by starting at the End Of File, not at the beginning...

```
property numberOfTimesRan : 0

set numberOfTimesRan to numberOfTimesRan + 1
display dialog "Number of tests ran to date: " & numberOfTimesRan & ""

set the logFile to ((path to desktop) as text) & "test.txt"
set the logText to numberOfTimesRan
try
    open for access file the logFile with write permission
    write ((logText as string) & return) to file the logFile --- starting at eof
    close access file the logFile
on error
    try
        close access file the logFile
    end try
end try
```

Also you were need to coerce the data to be a string

Comment: Once again you came to the rescue. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this...

```
property numberOfTimesRan : 0

set numberOfTimesRan to numberOfTimesRan + 1
display dialog "Number of tests ran to date: " & numberOfTimesRan

set the logFile to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "test.txt"
do shell script "echo " & numberOfTimesRan & " > " & quoted form of logFile
```